# App crashes after closing multiple QMessageBoxes

Tags: python, pyqt5

i have an odd problem with the GUI i am working on with Python using PyQt5.

The GUI has a single button that calls a class method which executes a Worker QThread.
In the Worker's run()-method I emit two consecutive signals that call the main GUIs show_messagebox()-method which displays a messagebox containing the information from the signal.

Displaying multiple QMessageBoxes works fine, but after closing the last one, the whole program including the main GUI exits/crashes. Unfortunately I don't get an error message.

Calling  self.show_messagebox.emit() only once in the run()-method works as intended and doesn't close the whole program.

I assume that for some reason the program thinks that the last remaining QMessageBox (the first one that gets emitted) becomes the parent and after closing it the program is done?

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution on how to solve this issue, which is why I decided to ask.

Here is the full source code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QWidget, QMessageBox

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    show_messagebox = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def run(self):
        self.show_messagebox.emit("Test1", "Test Text 1")
        self.show_messagebox.emit("Test2", "Test Text 2")

        self.finished.emit()


class WindowMain(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowMain, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("Start")

        self.messagebox = QMessageBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.execute)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.show()

    def execute(self):
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.worker.show_messagebox.connect(self.show_messagebox)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

        self.thread.start()

    def show_messagebox(self, title, text, icon=QMessageBox.Information):
        messagebox = QMessageBox()
        messagebox.setWindowTitle(title)
        messagebox.setText(text)
        messagebox.setIcon(icon)
        messagebox.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WindowMain()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Give the message-box a parent (i.e. `QMessageBox(self)`) and open it with `show()`.

Comment: Also, don't `deleteLater` the `self.worker` on its `finished` signal, but on `self.thread.finished`. When the worker object has finished, its thread is still running, so the worker object should not delete itself, but should be deleted when the related thread has finished.